# Exact Match in SOLR 5.1

Tags: java, lucene, schema, solr5

I have setup Solr 5.1.0 with proper data importation from MYSQL database. It is working good.

But I want exact match results or relevant to that only.

like,

```
Dancers in Mumbai
```

It gives all results which contains "dancers + mumbai" and only "dancers" + only "mumbai" keywords. I want result which must contains only "dancers + mumbai" not others.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a complete answer, but it's the direction I'm trying to take with a similar problem. Comments are very welcome.

Step 1:
Implement multiple Solr cores, core 1 is "jobs" (dancers/lawyers/etc), and core 2 is "cities" (mumbai/chennai/etc).

Step 2:
Query each core for exact matches, so implement the KeywordTokenizerFactory on the relevant field to find exact matches only. This will give you all the matches accross cores (e.g. jobs: dancers and cities:mumbai).

Step 3:
Perform your general query using EDisMax for a user-friendly search (e.g. searching for "dancers in mumbai" accross many fields),  and use the boost field to boost the jobs/cities found in the earlier query.

I would love to know if there is a better way of doing something this elaborate, but I have not found it yet. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Using required terms like: `+dancers +mumbia`

Or a phrase query: "dancers in mumbia"

Would work.

You can also set the default operator for your query to be "AND", [using the `q.op` parameter](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrQuerySyntax).

Comment: I have 2 different fields like **talent_name** & **city** both are independent. so it fetch data from both. but its gives results that contains only **dancers** & only **mumbai** contained results with common result. I want only that results which contains **dancer** as talent && **mumbai** as city.

Comment: @MayurChampaneria So, query for that.  I that case, a phrase query isn't really relevant, but either of the other two options will work just fine.  [Reading the query parser syntax documentation might help.](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/queryparser/org/apache/lucene/queryparser/classic/package-summary.html)